# While loop executing once before prompt

Tags: java, loops, input, while-loop

This was a difficult question to research, so please forgive me if this is a duplicate.

Basically, I have a while loop that'll only break if a code the user scans is an integer. I check this by trying `Integer.parseInt(integer)` and only breaks the loop if a NumberFormatException isn't thrown.

My problem, is that when the loop executes for the first time, the exception is thrown, without any user input.

Here's my code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true) 
{
    System.out.print("Please scan barcode: ");
    int inCode = 0;

    try
    {
        inCode = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Numbers only, please.");
    }

    if (inCode != 0) {
    // Do Stuff
    } else {
    System.out.println("Code can't be zero!");
    }
}
```

What *should* happen, is this:

> Please scan barcode: `// And here they enter the barcode`

But instead this happens:

> Please scan barcode: Numbers only, please.
>   Please scan barcode:

**EDIT:**

As per Bohemian's answer, I added the `continue` keyword to my code. That solves the issue, but only halfway. As per the request of the people who put my question on hold (With good reason, as I now see) I'll post a SSCCE for you guys. I'm going to remove the methods for interfacing with the database, though, only keeping the path that has the problem: creating a new account based on the code.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true)
{
        System.out.print("Please scan barcode: ");
        int inCode = 0;

        try
        {
            inCode = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Numbers only, please.");
            continue;
        }

        if (true) // Here it checks if an account associated with the code entered exists in the database. Because I'm having issues when it creates a new account, I've made this true.
        {
            System.out.println("No account associated with that code! Create one?");
            System.out.print("(yes/no): ");
            String answer = input.next();
            if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
            {
                System.out.println("Alright.");
                System.out.print("Please enter a name: ");
                String name = input.next();
                System.out.print("Alright. Now I'll add that to the database... ");

                // Here I add that to the database. Omitted.

                System.out.println("Done! Please scan again to interface.");
            }
            else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
            {
                System.out.println("Okay then.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Defaulting to no.");
            }
        }
}
// I still haven't written the code to interface with the account.
```

What happens now is, it says (in the first iteration)

> Please scan barcode:

But, after going through the process of adding the account, it loops again and says:

> Please scan barcode: Numbers only, please.
>   Please scan barcode:

**EDIT:**

Please note, everything is inside a `while` loop, so that when everything that the user has done is finished, it'll return to:

> Please scan barcode:

Comment: What's before this code?

Comment: What output does System.out.println(inCode)  give you after the try-catch part when you execute the while loop for the first time?

Comment: As Sotirios has hinted at, it's very likely that the problem is not actually in this snippet.  Can you post ALL of your code, instead of just the portion where YOU think the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {

    System.out.print("Please scan barcode: ");
    int inCode = 0;

    try {
        inCode = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        if (inCode != 0) {
            // Do Stuff
            break;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Numbers only, please.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is not a good idea  to create a new scanner in each iteration

Comment: And quite honestly there's no reason to be using `Scanner.next()` here when the input is an `int`. Plus, this doesn't *really* answer the question; he already *has* a `Scanner`.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have could be structured better, which would both make it clearer what is happening and easier to track down problems. You only want to loop on the data input - so just loop on the data input:

```
int inCode = 0;
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Please scan barcode: ");

    try {
        inCode = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        break;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Numbers only, please.");
    }
}

// Do stuff
```

You should consider using `scanner.hasNextInt()` and `scanner.nextInt()` rather than `scanner.next()` though. This will also avoid the need for using the exception like this. Normally using Exceptions to control program flow is a bad idea - really they should be used for handling exceptional circumstances. `Integer.parseInt` doesn't give you any alternatives, but scanner does.

Comment: um, that's going to break the loop with any input, and there's no reason to be using `next()` when the input is expected to be an int.

Answer (score 1):

After the edits, it's clear what the problem is: your `while (true)` loop doesn't have a `break` statement in it, so it will keep looping forever.

Personally, I'd suggest moving most of your code out of the loop, and only keeping the barcode-parsing code in it, e.g. like this:

```
int inCode;
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Please scan barcode: ");   
    try {
        inCode = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        if (inCode == 0) {
            System.out.println("Code can't be zero!");
        } else {
            break;  // we got a valid barcode! end the loop and move on...
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Numbers only, please.");
        // no need for a "continue" here, since the loop will restart anyway
    }
}

// rest of the code here...
```

or possibly even:

```
int inCode;
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Please scan barcode: ");   
    try {
        inCode = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Numbers only, please.");
        continue;
    }
    if (inCode == 0) {
        System.out.println("Code can't be zero!");
        continue;
    }
    break;  // we have a valid barcode! end the loop and move on...
}

// rest of the code here...
```

Comment: It's supposed to loop forever. The point of having it in a `while` loop is so that it'll return to the beginning (`Please scan barcode: `) when the user has finished interfacing.

Answer (score 0):

I would just `continue` the loop if there's bad input, then you don't need to test it later:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Please scan barcode: ");
    int inCode = 0;

    try {
        inCode = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Numbers only, please.");
        continue; // ADDED THIS LINE
    }

    // Do Stuff with inCode
}
```

Note that by your code testing for zero after the input, you preclude zero as valid input. This code allows any number, *including* zero. Small point, but there's no worries about edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
String in=null;
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Please scan barcode: ");
    int inCode = 0;
    try {
        in= input.next();
        inCode=Integer.parseInt(in);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Numbers only, please.");
    }

if (inCode != 0) {
// Do Stuff
} else {
// Repeat loop
}
```

or you can directly read an integer through Scanner object instead of using `Integer.parseInt()` method.

```
int inCode=0;
while(true) {
  System.out.print("Please scan barcode : ");
  inCode=input.nextInt();

  if(inCode!=0){ //do stuff }
  else { //Repeat Loop }
 }
```

Comment: I have tried using nextInt, and that illustrates the core of my problem: `Please scan barcode: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException` Something is inputed into the Scanner object before the user even touches the barcode scanner. What gives?